Serial Killer killing people and keeping their heads
I have seen this movie some scenes I remember are:

The killer is a man in his late 30's or 40's
He has a house in the woods also, where he brings his last victim (female young) and tells her the story of her wife
The movie is dark, it's suspense and thriller. It also features a detective, I think its a female, she catches him before he murders the last girl
He goes to a woman's house, kills her and keeps her head
He keeps the body parts of his victims, especially heads in jars.
It is not from the 80's 90's, Its from 00's I think
He mostly targets women

It was in English, can't name any actors. It was based in a city where women were disappearing, a cop/detective was asked to find him. At the end she did find him and I think the last girl was her daughter. The season in movie was winter.

This more ot less sounds like Shiver from 2012.

Wendy Alden, a young secretary in Portland lacking in self- confidence becomes victim of a savage killer who has claimed the lives of a number of other women. Somehow Wendy finds the resources of courage to fight back and escape.

The serial killer beheads women and stores their heads in jars, and the movie takes place in winter and features the protagonist's mom and a female cop as characters, but the main detective is played by Casper Van Dien. Here's the trailer:



